# Is there a way we can provide default data on API fail in RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I am trying RTK Query for the first time to fetch some data in a react + ts application. Is there a way where I could specify some default data if the API fails? What is the good practice that should be followed here?

```
export const dummyApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'dummyApi',
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ['Dummy'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getDummy: builder.query<DummyItem[], void>({
      query: () => `/dummy`,
      providesTags: ['Dummy'],
      transformResponse: (response: DummyApiResponse) =>
        return [...someDefaultListOfItems, ...response.data];
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

I tried something in `transformErrorResponse` but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const handleError = (args, { queryFulfilled }) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
  } catch (error) {
    // return default data in here
  }
};
```

```js
export const dummyApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'dummyApi',
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ['Dummy'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getDummy: builder.query<DummyItem[], void>({
      query: () => `/dummy`,
      providesTags: ['Dummy'],
      transformResponse: (response: DummyApiResponse) =>
        return [...someDefaultListOfItems, ...response.data];
      },
      onQueryStarted: handleError
    }),
  }),
});
```

You can try onQueryStarted API and handle error by using try catch block as my example. Hope it's helfull.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get the part what you explained. Now in the function itself, when you say return data - Do you mean to use `updateCachedData`  or something else?

Comment: UPDATE: I updated my catch block code like this and it worked. Is this an optimal way or is there any other way that is meant to be a good practice? 

`dispatch(dummyApi.util.upsertQueryData('getDummy', undefined, someDefaultListOfItems));`

Comment: It seem like a good way. Thank for your update.